# Why "width: -moz-fit-content" does not work on input[type=text]?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an input element autogrowable depending on its content. I know it can be done with help of a little js code. But I want to  achive it with only CSS.

While -moz-fit-content perfectly works on DIV element, it does not work on INPUT. So I wonder why is so.

```css
.input {
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="4 000" class="input" />

<div class="input" contenteditable="true">4 000</div>
```

Comment: an input has no content from the CSS perspective ... its value doesn't count as content

Comment: yeah right @Temani Afif

Answer (score 0):

try using this code:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';" value="4 000" class="input" />
```

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned in description, I know it's easy to do with JS. But I need CSS solution.